# Core Data grouping data in table

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data, uitableview

I am using core data trying to create a simple database app, I have an entity called "Game" which has a "creator". I have basically used the iPhone table view template and replaced the names. I have the games listed by creator.  Currently the tableview looks like this...

Chris Ryder
Chris Ryder
Chris Ryder
Chris Ryder
Dan Grimaldi
Dan Grimaldi
Dan Grimaldi
Scott Ricardo
Tim Thermos
Tim Thermos

I am trying to group the tableview, so that each creator has only one cell in the tableview and is listed once and only once like this...

Chris Ryder
Dan Grimaldi
Scott Ricardo
Tim Thermos

any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking.  What is the goal of your data model?  More information about whist you are trying to accomplish and where you are getting stuck will help you get better answers.

### Update

You are going to need to use a relationship.  Why are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: I have an entity called "Game" which has a "creator" string attribute and a "gameName" string attribute.

Im trying to get the UITableView to display one cell representing A creator despite him being the creator of multiple games.  With out using relationships.

Right now for every object in the "game" entity has its own cell, despite being by the same "creator".

So for instance...

Object 1.
Creator: Robert Frost
Game: Solitaire

Object 2.
Creator: Robert Frost
Game: PeaKnuckle

shows up as two individual cells when I only want one cell to represent Robert Frost.